Kubernetes: Influxdb 1.8.10 container can’t create users
I deployed on docker InfluxDB v 1.8.10 with command:
docker run --name influxdb -t
-e INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=“true”
-e INFLUXDB_DB=“mydatabase”
-e INFLUXDB_USER=“user”
-e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=“user”
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=“admin”
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=“admin”
–restart unless-stopped
-d influxdb:1.8.10

When I connect I see that the new Admin user is created.
Now I would like to deploy it on Kubernetes, this is my code:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
    name: influxdb
    namespace: mon-grafana
spec:
  serviceName: influxdb
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     app: influxdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: influxdb
        image: influxdb:1.8.10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
          name: influxdb
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 500Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 500Mi
        env:
        - name: INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: INFLUXDB_DB
          value: "mydatabase"
        - name: INFLUXDB_USER
          value: "user"
        - name: INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD
          value: "user"
        - name: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc-influxdb
          mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb
        - name: influxdb-config
          mountPath: "/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf"
          subPath: influxdb.conf
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      volumes:
      - name: influxdb-config
        configMap:
          name: configmap
          items:
          - key: influxdb.conf
            path: influxdb.conf
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pvc-influxdb
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi

this is my infliuxdb.conf file:
root@influxdb-0:/# cat /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
reporting-enabled = false

[meta]
dir = “/var/lib/influxdb/meta”

[data]
dir = “/var/lib/influxdb/data”
wal-dir = “/var/lib/influxdb/wal”
max-series-per-database = 1000000
max-values-per-tag = 100000
index-version = “tsi1”
max-index-log-file-size = “100k”

[http]
log-enabled = false
enabled = true
bind-address = “0.0.0.0:8086”
https-enabled = false
flux-enabled = true

After deploy it in Kubernetes, the Admin user is not created during deploy, and when I try to connect I receive this error:

root@influxdb-0:/# influx -username admin -password admin Connected to
http://localhost:8086 version 1.8.10 InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.10
show databases; ERR: error authorizing query: create admin user first
or disable authentication Warning: It is possible this error is due to
not setting a database. Please set a database with the command “use ”.

How can create the Admin user during the initial deploy (like I did in docker)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Marcello, thanks for your reply, and sorry for the confusion. I updated my question. I need to create an Admin user during InfluxDB deploy in Kubernetes like I did using docker container, but in Kubernetes enable authentication without create admin user
